# What is the equation needed to find the area of a regular polygon within a circle when given no. of sides and radius?

Tags: python

I am trying to create an algorithm to find the area of polygons in a circle when given the radius of the circle and the no. of sides of the polygon

```
def area_of_polygon_inside_circle(circle_radius, number_of_sides):

    area = ?

    rounding = str(round(area, 1))
    rounding=float(rounding)
    return rounding
```

Comment: This is a geometry problem, not a programming problem

Comment: Do you know the formula? Paste it in your query so we understand what you trying to implement.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about practical computer programming but rather belongs on [Mathematics Stack Exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/) once the questioner has added more of his own work and explained just where he is stuck.

Answer (score 1):

Next time try to find the formula yourself. It's very easy to look it up online. SO is meant for specific programming problems while you are looking for a formula.

```
from math import sin, pi    

area = (1.0/2.0) * number_of_sides * (circle_radius **2) * sin(2.0 * pi / number_of_sides)
```

Converting the value to string after rounding is redundant as well.

```
rounding = round(area, 1)
```

Suffices perfectly

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this:

```
import math
def area_poly_inscribed_in_circle(radius,sides):
    side_radius = (sides * radius * radius)/2
    sin_angle = math.sin(2*3.1416/sides)
    return side_radius * sin_angle



area_poly_inscribed_in_circle(5,6)
```